# Problem with call of Methods of AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am trying to update the progress bar,using AsyncTask
My Code looks like this

```
private class ProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
{
 protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
 {
    int a=2;
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i=i+5)
    {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        publishProgress(i);
    }
    return a;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... item) 
 {
    //int no_of_argruments=item.length;
    tv.setText("Over !!"+item[0]);
    bar.setProgress(item[0]);
 }

protected void onPostExecute()
{
    if(result[0]!=null)
    {
        tv.setText("Hurray !!");
        Toast.makeText(checkThread.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    }
}
```

But upon the completipon of doInBackground(),my onPostExecute() is not called,the progress bar just hangs up to it's final value.

How to call the onPostExecute() Method ??

Answer (score 0):

This is correct signature for postExecute()

```
protected void onPostExecute (Result result)
```

Your method is your own method that `AsyncTask` has no knowledge about.